# Splitting SVG Paths Programmatically

Tags: svg

I have an SVG image consisting exclusively of **straight** line segments connected by nodes. I wish to apply a transform on the coordinates of those nodes of the form (x,y) --> (x',y') such that x' = f(x,y), y' = g(x,y) but **only** in a certain region of the xy plane.

My question is this: if there is a node *inside* this region connected with a straight line segment to a node *outside* this region how do I split this line segment at the boundary of the region so that two nodes are created, as close as possible to each other on either side of the boundary, leaving behind a tiny gap in the original line segment at the boundary. The idea is to create two line segments from the original single line segment, with four nodes in total instead of two, and then apply the transform to the two nodes of the line segment *inside* the region and **not** to the two nodes of the line  segment *outside* the region.

Note: The mathematics behind this are not the issue, the issue is programming it. This splitting business will of necessity require the creation of additional paths, which I don't quite know how to program. Any programming language would be fine, so long as it got the job done. If it is of any help, I am using Inkscape for editing the SVG. Thanks.

Comment: Do you intend to write the necessary SVG parser framework yourself, or are you going to rely on either an existing library or trust on a "quick and dirty" parsing routine?

Comment: "Do you intend to write the necessary SVG parser framework yourself?" Yes. But I don't know how to do it. Hence my question. "Are you going to rely on an existing library?" Definitely not.

Comment: Well ... at its root, SVG is plain XML. All it needs is recognizing the objects of interest (which should well be documented elsewhere), and at that point you will be able to scan for your paths and lines, and modify, delete, and insert them. But that basic requirement - a full, compliant, robust XML parser - is a rather tall task in itself. Hence my question. Don't you think it is a bit too broad for Stack Overflow? (A-ha. Please read at least the [tour], and then check the [help/on-topic] to see what's considered on topic for SO!)

Comment: In that case, do you know any XML parsers that would allow me to do what I described above?

Comment: In case you are still wondering ;-) You can use any xml library like `lxml`. Iterate over the nodes of a path in a pairwise fashion. Check for each pair, if your split criteria apply. If not, just copy the nodes to the output path. If the path should be split, add two new nodes at the desired split position, for example at `[(x-x')/2, (y-y')/2]` or at the intersection with your region boundaries. Add one of these nodes to the current output path, then end it. Start a new path and add the other new node as first node to it. Then continue with the nodes of the original path.